# How to delete an item from list view without iterating

Tags: android-listview, android

I have a an `ArrayList<Color> colorList` for my list view with an `ArrayAdapter`. My POJO like this:

```
public class Color {
 int id;
 String name;
 //getter setter
}
```

Everything is fetched from the server. so the `id` of each color object will match an `id` in the DB table.

In my `ArrayAdapter's` `getView` I am setting the tag with an `id` from the database.

```
    holder.imageButton.setTag(item.getId());  //color id from database
    holder.imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int id = (Integer) v.getTag();  
            new DeleteColor(id).execute();
        }
    });
```

In the above code I am sending the clicked item's `id` to the server for deletion

What is the easy way to remove an item from my listView?

What I'm doing right now is:

```
class DeleteColor extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    int id;
    public DeleteColor (int id) {
      this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground (String ... args) {
        MyManager.INSTANCE.getService().deleteColor(id, new Callback<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Integer id, Response response) { 
                //loop through the colorlist to find which one to remove
                for (int i = 0; i < colorList.size(); i++) {
                    Color c = colorList.get(i);
                    if (c.getId() == id) {
                        colorList.remove(c);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {

            }
        });
        return "";
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am looping through the entire `colorList` to find out the one that has the `id` I want removed and then removing it. Is this a good approach to achieve this?

**Question**

How can I avoid looping through the entire `colorList` to find the one that needs to be deleted.

Comment: call the `notifyDataSetChanged()` in the `onPostExecute()` method.

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't solve my problem of looping over the entire list to find which item to delete. the solution I have now is working ok. But you are right, I could move `notifyDataSetChanged()` to `onPostExecute()`

Comment: Both J0hj0h and Sound Conception are basically right here. indexOf() is probably the easiest way in terms of readability (but that's up to you do decide). The source for indexOf() does basically what you're doing but also does null checking.

The trouble with a List is that remove is an O(n) operation. If you need remove to beat O(n), you could possibly store the colors in a Map, but without looking at your full code, I'm not sure if that would cause other complications. Honestly though, short of millions of colors, O(n) should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the id of the object you want to remove from the list.
Use that id to get the object, then use the ArrayList method `indexOf(Object object)` to find the index of the object in your list and remove it.

Answer (score 1):

There technically is no way to directly access an item in a list.
In school we built a list in Java ourselves and it consisted of different entries that were connected one to another. But the first only was connected to the second and that in turn only to the third. So you couldn't even access the object on the second place, without beginning at the top. To access anything you had to iterate the list.

I just read Sound Conception's answer and I'm pretty sure that the `indexOf(Object)`-method itself iterates through the whole list (unless the Java developers did some magic, which actually could be. ;) I'm not a professional and haven't looked into the code of that method). But your manual looping probably is the most efficient way.

I don't think, there is a practical difference in execution time. So you might want to use Sound Conception's method to keep the code simple. It's totally up to you!

Answer (score 0):

There is one another way if you set the item position as tag on your view.....

Then v.getId() will give you the position clicked and that you can directly remove from your list as arraylist.remove(positionclicked);